# How do I close results file on failed test? Using Webdriver, c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, teardown

I'm trying to create a customised results file for tests using Selenium Webdriver in c#.

I'm writing the results to a csv file, and closing it at the end.

The problem is that if the test fails and doesn't complete, the file is never closed, and therefore I don't get the results.

I've tried putting the file.Close(); in the Teardown section, but that doesn't work because "file" does not exist in that context. I can't see a way to pass it in.

I also tried setting up the new StreamWriter file in Setup - which was fine to do, but didn't help close it at the end.

I have searched on here and a general google search.

Here is a sample of what works - when it all passes (all in one place - different classes in test).

I want to be able to move the file.Close(); to where it will run regardless of whether it's passed or not.

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());

     //   file.Close();
     // this is where it doesn't work if I put it here
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheTest()
    {           
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\results\test.csv", true);

        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("text", "text");
            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "time", "test", "PASS");
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "time", "test", "FAIL");
        }

        //do next step

        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Try declaring `file` as a public at `class` level, so that it will be available for all methods of your class

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You are not disposing of the object. Trying a using statement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx

```
[Test]
    public void TheTest()
    {           
        using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\results\test.csv", true))
{

        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("text", "text");
            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "time", "test", "PASS");
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "time", "test", "FAIL");
        }

        //do next step

        }
    }
```